# Analytical view on stochastic differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have seen that in option pricing problems (Black-Scholes (BSE)), various asset price dynamics $S_t$ are assumed to derive models. For the Generalized Black-Scholes equation (GBSE), we can see that the change in stock price $dS$ of the underlying satisfies the stochastic differential equation
$$dS = (\mu- D)S dt + \sigma S dW,$$
where $μ$ is the drift rate, $D$ is the dividend yield, $σ$ is the market volatility, and $dW$ is the increment of a standard Wiener process. How can we treat the above equation as a 'differential equation' since the increment $dW$ is taken from a mere continuous function (random variable)? How the so-called 'differential equation' is sensible throughout the genesis of a partial differential equation(GBSE)?

Further, In some models like Jump-diffusion BSE, Jump discontinuity is even assumed in the process. How do we justify the analysis (real) of such models?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: @Jacob Manaker Sorry Sir, Can you specify? Do you indicate the applications of R-S integrals in probability theory as it suggests the formulation for expectation? Can you mention how it connected with the posted query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to explain this in terms a sequence of steps of increasing generality.

N.b.: **There are some technical flaws in my presentation below.**  It's been a while since I learned this, and I clearly misremember some details.  See Paresseux Nguyen's comment below, which cites the standard texts for the argument.  I haven't yet digested exactly how to fix my mistakes; once I do, I'll try to correct the presentation.

#### 1. Replace the differential equation with an integral equation

You seem to implicitly assume that $$dS=(\mu-D)S\,dt+\sigma S\,dW$$ is shorthand for "the equation $$\frac{dS(t)}{dt}=(\mu-D)S(t)+\sigma S(t)\frac{dW(t)}{dt}$$ holds for any $t$."  Instead, interpret it as shorthand for "the equation $$\int_{t=0}^{t=T}{dS(t)}=\int_0^T{(\mu-D)S(t)\,dt}+\int_{t=0}^{t=T}{\sigma S(t)\,dW(t)}$$ holds for any $T$."

If everything is smooth, then both representations are equivalent by the fundamental theorem of calculus.  Of course, *not* everything is smooth; that's the thrust of your question!  It turns out the definition of an integral tolerates rough functions much better than that of a derivative.

#### 2. The Riemann-Stieltjes-Young integral

Given functions $f$ and $g$, define (when it exists) $$\int_{t=0}^T{f(t)\,dg(t)}=\lim_{\lambda\vdash[0,T]}{\sum_{[y,z]\in\lambda}{f(x_{[y,z]})(g(z)-g(y))}}$$ where the limit is over further refinement of the partition $\lambda$ and should be invariant over all possible choices of $x_{[y,z]}\in[y,z]$.  One can then show:

- If $g(t)=t$, then this reduces to the classical Riemann integral $$\int_0^T{f(t)\,dt}$$
- If $g$ is differentiable, then $$\int_{t=0}^T{f(t)\,dg(t)}=\int_0^T{f(t)g'(t)\,dt}$$
- The integral exists as long as $f$ is continuous and $g$ has bounded variation.

Of course, functions of bounded variation are differentiable a.e., so Brownian motion $W$ cannot be of bounded variation.

OTOH, $W$ is $\frac{1}{2-\epsilon}$-Hölder.  As it turns out, that's enough.

#### 3. Rough paths theory

Define the $p$-variation of a function $f$ on $[0,T]$ to be $$V_p(f,[0,T])=\lim_{\lambda\vdash[0,T]}{\sqrt[p]{\sum_{[x,y]\in\lambda}{|f(y)-f(x)|^p|}}}$$ with the obvious modifications if $p=\infty$.  A function is bounded if it has finite $\infty$-variation and of bounded variation if it has finite $1$-variation.  Brownian motion has finite $2$-variation.

From Hölder's inequality, if $f$ has finite $p$-variation, $g$ has finite $q$-variation, and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, then there exists a Riemann-Stieltjes-Young integral $$\int_{t=0}^T{f(t)\,dg(t)}$$

As mentioned, Brownian motion has finite $2$-variation, as does the solution to any Brownian SDE.  Thus the integrals in $$\int_{t=0}^{t=T}{dS(t)}=\int_0^T{(\mu-D)S(t)\,dt}+\int_{t=0}^{t=T}{\sigma S(t)\,dW(t)}$$ all exist in the Riemann-Stieltjes-Young sense.

Comment: Nice presentation, but wrong. Brownian motion does not have finite 2-variation. (c.f. Duke Math. J. 39(2): 219-241 (June 1972)). Moreover, integrals in  Riemann-Stieltjes-Young sense require $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}>1$. These problems are some of motivations that we define "signature of path" and construct the vast theory of rough path based on it. (see Differential Equations Driven by Rough Paths
École d’Été de Probabilités de Saint-Flour XXXIV - 2004- Terry J. Lyons
Michael Caruana · Thierry Lévy).

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen: (1) Note that my definition of $p$-variation takes a net-theoretic limit towards the infinitely fine partition, whereas the classical $p$-variation is just a sup over all partitions.  IIRC, the limit is equivalent to taking the mesh to zero, in which case Brownian motion is known to have finite quadratic variation.  Am I misremembering that, and "$\text{mesh}\to0$" is a stronger condition?  (2) $p^{-1}+q^{-1}>1$ rings a bell — I originally had $\geq1$, then dropped it as clouding the use of Hölder.  Is it easy to explain why classical Hölder (equality) is insufficient?

Comment: ...And, rereading this, I see I just copied the classical definition which uses a sup.  _Derp_; sorry; I've edited that mistake away.

Comment: @JacobManaker, Paresseus Nguyen In fact, the terms ($\frac{dS}{dt}$ and $\frac{dW}{dt}$) are considered in a generalized derivative sense, right?

Comment: @MessiLio: Yes, definitely.  That's why I say you should consider it shorthand for an integral equation, not a differential one.  (I know I still haven't fixed the errors in this piece; I got distracted by other topics but it's still on my to-do list.)

Comment: @JacobManaker I feel your explanation is highly helpful, lot of thanks, and, I hope we will fill the gaps soon.

Comment: I think this still is incorrect, in particular the statement "should be invariant over all possible choices of $x_{[y,z]} \in [y,z]$.  For stochastic integrals, the choice of $x_{[y,z]} \in [y,z]$ matters a lot.  The standard Ito integral is a limit (in probability) if you take $x_{[y,z]} = y$.  If you take $x_{[y,z]} = z$, you get the Stratonovich integral, and other choices of $x_{[y,z]}$ lead to other integrals.

Comment: @user6247850 Thanks for the heads-up.  I'll add that to the list of things to check when I get back to this piece.